# Bind a value on ngModel in another components Angular 7

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, angular7

let say i have this component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  template: `<div class="border">
  <h1>Simple Date Converter</h1>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>Input RFC-3339 Formatted Date:</p>

    <div id="in" class="block">
      <input #myInput [(ngModel)]="inputValue">
        <br> <br>
        <button class="btn" [routerLink]="['result']">Convert Date</button>

        <p>{{ inputValue | date:'EEEE, d MMMM, y' }}</p>
    </div>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>  `,
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and then when i clicked the button it should route to another component like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-result',
  template: `<div class="results">
  <h1>Simple Date Converter</h1>
  <br> <br>
  <p>Converted result</p>
  <br><br>
  <p>{{ inputValue | date:'EEEE, d MMMM, y' }}</p>
  <br>
  <a routerLink="">back to main page</a>
  </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./result.component.css']
})
export class ResultComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

the question is how can i bind / use the value on "inputValue" on the first component in another component like the result component, some people advice me to use event emitter but it somehow doesn't work for me, i'm new on angular 7, so i don't know if the syntax is wrong or anything else in that matter, so i decided to display the entire components here so maybe you guys can understand the situation

Comment: can you guide me how to or there is a tutorial i could learn from?

Comment: What happen when you click `Convert Date`?

Comment: it routes to the ResultComponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways how two components can communicate:

- services
- some store (ngrx)
- inputs/outputs
- passing state through router (eg. query params, params, state)
- ...

In your case they are not having parent/child relationship as they are routed components so you cannot use inputs/outputs, but you can use everything else.

In your case i would suggest to pass the state when navigating.

```
<button class="btn" [routerLink]="['result']" [state]="{inputValue: inputValue}">Convert Date</button>
```

and then you can access the state in the second component:

```
export class ResultComponent implements OnInit {
    inputValue;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.inputValue = history.state.inputValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it, but

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.inputValue = history.state.inputValue;
}

give error  "message": "Property 'inputValue' does not exist on type 'ResultComponent'."

Comment: you have to add it to the component, i have updated answer

Comment: now it didn't give error, that's something, but can i just use the state to a html tag on the result component like 
  <p>{{ inputValue }}</p>
?

Comment: sure, every public property from your component is accessible in the template